Select onChange Error - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.props.inputProps.ref')
"use client";

import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import PhoneInput from "@/components/PhoneInput";
import countryList from "react-select-country-list";
import Select from "react-select";

export default async function Dashboard() {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), []);

  return (
          <form className="bg-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:rounded-xl md:col-span-2">
                <div className="sm:col-span-4">
                  <label htmlFor="country" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                    Country
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-2">
                    <Select
                      id="country"
                      name="country"
                      options={options}
                      value={country}
                      onChange={(selectedOption) => setCountry(selectedOption.value)}
                      autoComplete="country-name"
                      className="block w-full  py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-xs     "
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
             
          </form>
  );
}

The country select onChange is throwing the following error when I select a country:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.props.inputProps.ref')
I logged selectedOption and it came out to {label:"United States",value:"US}
What can be the issue and how do I fix it?

I believe selectedOption is a value, not an object. Replace this part by onChange={setCountry}

The error you're seeing (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.props.inputProps.ref')) suggests that the Select component is expecting some props to be provided or is having trouble managing the ref internally when used with useState for country.
In this case, the issue might arise from how value is being set. When you set value={country}, you’re directly assigning it a string, which is not what react-select expects for the value prop. Instead, react-select expects an object containing both label and value properties.
Solution
To fix this, you can store the entire selectedOption object in your state, rather than just the value:
Update country in your useState to store the selected option object.
Modify the onChange handler to set the entire option.
Ensure value is the selected object, not just the value property.
Here’s how your code should look:
"use client";

import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import PhoneInput from "@/components/PhoneInput";
import countryList from "react-select-country-list";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);
  const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), []);

  return (
    <form className="bg-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:rounded-xl 
     md:col-span-2">
      <div className="sm:col-span-4">
        <label
          htmlFor="country"
          className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
        >
          Country
        </label>
        <div className="mt-2">
          <Select
            id="country"
            name="country"
            options={options}
            value={country}
            onChange={(selectedOption) => setCountry(selectedOption)}
            autoComplete="country-name"
            className="block w-full py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-xs"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

